# Import 'schema.sql' file into PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm moving a site from one server to another and have successfully moved the files over and setup a new mySQL database. I've then imported the old database into the new one and that all works fine.
I also have another file that I was supplied and I am having trouble importing it. It is a 'schema.sql' file. Could someone please explain what this is and how I would go about importing it into/alongside my other database? Many thanks!

Comment: if it's a straight sql file you should be able to run it like you would any other sql commands

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm a bit new to all this DB stuff. How would I run the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin

```
1. Databases -> Create Database -> Set name and correct collation -> Create

2. Choose newly created database in left pane

3. Import -> File to import -> Choose file -> Click Go
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, I get the following error message: Error
SQL query:
--
-- Table structure for table `actions`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  `actions` ;
MySQL said: 
#1046 - No database selected

Comment: You need to create a database first and then import into it. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks - I don't have an option to create a new database in phpMyAdmin under Databases! It just list the databases I have!

Comment: Click on Home icon in left pane, then Databases in horizontal toolbar.  If you have appropriate rights then you'll see Create Database option right above the list of existing databases. If you don't have rights it will tell you 'No privileges'

Comment: If you're in a hosting environment then you should create your db with cPanel and then manage it with phpMyAdmin

Comment: Hi Peterm - your correct, create in CP, manage in phpMyAdmin. All working now - thanks!